# Java on MacOS Monterey

Tags: java, installation

I've installed java 8 jdk, but javac is not working. Also, the operating system has java blocked. Is there any way to fix this? I am using macOS Monterey.

Comment: You’ll need to explain each of your first two sentences in detail. Also, how have none of the many existing Questions and Answers on this topic not addressed your issue?

Answer (score 0):

`brew install java`

In case of a build error, check the output and you may see a suggestion to create a symbolic link and run the command again.

https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-install-java-on-mac-osx/